# Jackson jar hell when installing my plugin on elasticsearch

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch

I am writing a custom plugin for Elasticsearch and this plugin has a dependency on Jackson library. When I installed the plugin on Elasticsearch, I got this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to load plugin AdapterPlugin due to jar hell
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: jar hell!
>   class: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Base64Variant
>   jar1: C:\elasticsearch-6.2.4\lib\jackson-core-2.8.10.jar
>   jar2: C:\elasticsearch-6.2.4\plugins.installing-4501343069579282727\jackson-core-2.8.10.jar
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkClass(JarHell.java:275)
>           at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.JarHell.checkJarHell(JarHell.java:192)
>           at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.checkBundleJarHell(PluginsService.java:473)
>           ... 12 more

how can I resolve this problem? As you see I tried to change my Jackson version from latest version to 2.8.10(which elastic 6.2.4 use it) but that did'nt help.

I am using maven and here is my pox.xml file that I am using for my cuatom plugin:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.10</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you include your dependencies on the class path? Maven? Gradle? Need more information. If you use Maven you can use exclusions when adding Elasticsearch and include the jackson lib yourself:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Yes I am using maven. but I tried your solution and still got the same error.

Comment: That means you probably configured maven wrong. Can you update the question with your pom file?

Comment: SOF does not allow me to add more codes becuase my description is short. I've added dependencies part to my post, is that enough?

Comment: Yes, but you dont exclude anything. See my code on how to exclude a certain dependency from another.

Comment: I tried your solution and still getting the same error as I told you. the only difference is my scope for elastic is "provided". is this a problem?

Comment: Might be, because "provided" are not transitive dependencies meaning exclusion probably does not work with them. Did you try "compile"? Why do you need "provided"?

Answer (score 0):

Shortest answer I got:
[image]

In case the image is not visible: it's a comment from [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/jar-hell-exception/162824) dev at Elastic saying

> Don't ship jackson within your plugin.

That's all.